# How to call a macro from within another macro in Notepad++?

Tags: macros, notepad++

Does anybody know how to call a macro from within another macro in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Record the first macro
- Save it
- Create a shortcut key to the first macro
- Record the second macro
- Press the shortcut key for the first macro
- Save the second macro

**References**

- Notepad++ Docs: Macros ([http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Macros](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/macros/))